# Cache-Manifest How to handle authentication cookies?

Tags: html, authentication, cache-manifest

How are authentication cookies read/stored when using cache-manifest?

I am using cache manifest to speed up a jquery-mobile app that has a browser baseline of Safari Mobile.  I am using the multi-page template and within in one of the pages, I make an ajax request to my server for dynamic data.

The issue I am encountering is that when I cache the multi page template(index.html), it technically is not authenticated during subsequent reloads/views and when I make the ajax request, the server is not able to read an expected cookie value to bypass the ACL and thus allow the get request.

Thank you in advance for replies.

Comment: I'm having the same problem I think. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: No we ultimately removed the cache manifest before shipping the product.  It still seems to be an unanswered issue. Please update this thread if you find a solution.

Comment: Turns out our issue wasn't with cookies, but with a self signed SSL certificate we were using on the website that would cause AJAX requests to fail because since the index.html was being loaded from the cache the browser never displayed that warning allowing the user to opt to accept the self signed certificate.

Comment: For your cookie issue I would suggest using AJAX to request some resource that would return you the cookies you need or you can even make the cookies in javascript if their value is known.

Comment: Going to look into the self signed SSL cert possibility. Nice catch!